# How do I express a degree on my CV that I have completed but have not been awarded?

Tags: cv, degree, terminology, graduation, credentials

I have completed all the requirements for an M.S. degree and have filed the appropriate paperwork. All I have left to do is walk at the end of this semester. I want to put this on my CV, but it seems appropriate to differentiate it from my Ph.D., which is (only) "In progress", and another M.S. which I completed a few years ago.

**How should I express this on my CV?** Should I say "Anticipated" or "Expected", with the date?

My question is different than [Should one list incomplete degrees on a CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/should-one-list-incomplete-degrees-on-a-cv) because that question asks about a degree that was entirely incomplete, unawarded, and is not likely to ever be awarded. In my situation, the degree needs only to be formally awarded.

Comment: 'Complete, to be awarded 5/2016'? How will it show up on your transcript right now?

Comment: I like @Jon Custer's comment better than the suggested phrasings in the two answers.  The answer of postagepaid would give me the right idea, after I puzzled out the somewhat unfamiliar phrasing.  The answer of O.R. Mapper would give me the wrong idea: that the work of the degree was not yet complete.

Answer (score 4):

If for example it's a PhD which has been ratified but not officially conferred, you can write:

PhD (Discipline) Awaiting Conferral.

Comment: This is the term I am most familiar with as well.

Answer (score 2):

For in-progress degrees, you should indicate the expected approximate date of completion. For instance, if the only open action is waiting till the end of your semester and then deterministically going through one bureaucratic hoop, you would write:

> in progress: M.S. (estimated date of completion: March 2016)

If you would like to volunteer more details about the single steps still missing, you can do so, but only if the total length of the CV warrants such details - in overall short CVs, the reader will be more interested in the details of the steps you have actually completed than in your upcoming plans.