# Including incomplete or complete BS after MS in résumé

Tags: cv

I have just got a MS in Math and I'm about to start a PhD program also in Math. The problem is that before starting the Math program I dropped out of a combined BS+MS program in Computer Science after ~3 years. I'm not sure about how, or even if, I should include that info in my résumé.

I'm considering some possibilities and I'd appreciate it if you could give me some advice on them.

1. Include that incomplete BS+MS program in Computer Science in my
   résumé.

   Pro: show part of my undergrad academic background. Con: being percieved
   as a dropout.
2. Stop including that incomplete BS+MS program in Computer Science in
   my résumé.

   Pro: not being percieved as a dropout. Con: not showing a part of my
   academic background.
3. I need only four credits to finish the BS part of the Computer
   Science program. It will demand me only a light additional workload to get
   them in two or three semesters while working on my PhD. I could finish
   the BS part of the Computer Science program and start mentioning it in my résumé only after having completed it.

   Pro: I'll be showing a BS diploma in a related field. Con: the
   graduating date for the BS in Computer Science will be after getting
   the MS in Math, so that could be seen as a lack of direction in my
   career.

I think that this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/should-one-list-incomplete-degrees-on-a-cv) one because I'm considering also the possibility of actually finishing the incomplete BS program and how it compares to inlcuding or not information about it if I don't get the diploma.

---

**EDIT for clarification**

I already have a BS and a MS in Math and I've been admitted for a Math PhD. I want to know how I should expect to be judgen when applying for a future postdoc or applied math job if I happen to add a Computer Science BS diploma in between the Math MS and the Math PhD.

The intuitive answer to me would be that, if after finishing my PhD I'm able to prove that I've work hard, adding in that BS in the résumé should not harm. But I'm also considering the possibility of being judged as lacking direction in my career.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important question is what are you using this resume for? You say you're "about to start on a PhD program also in Math" -- does that mean you already got accepted? Are you looking to get summer jobs?

My main concern is if you have a PhD degree, a Masters degree, and another Bachelors degree, you won't have enough space to list other degrees (especially if you want to list relevant coursework). You'll hopefully get teaching experience, work experience, and leadership skills to fill out the rest of your resume.

If you don't have another Bachelors degree, what did you list when you were applying to the Masters? I would just follow whatever you did there. It might seem odd that you have a Masters but no Bachelors degree.

Comment: I already have a BS+MS in Math and I've been admitted for the Math PhD. I want to know how would they judge my application for a future postdoc if I happen to add a Computer Science BS diploma in between the Math MS and the Math PhD.

Comment: You'll probably want to use a CV when applying for a postdoc, which basically means you'll include everything,

Your school may have a career advisor (or someone else experienced) you can ask about how to phrase it in your specific case. You'll be able to explain your situation more fully and get more individualized advice than you might on the internet.